# Need advice about how to cache text data on iPhone

Tags: iphone, caching

Could you give me some algorithm or example?

Comment: What do you mean by "cache"? Do you mean "persist"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` will nicely hold onto snippets of data.

Example:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kTabIndexKey])
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kTabIndexKey];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:tabBarController.selectedIndex forKey:kTabIndexKey];
}
```

Persists and loads an integer (your method would be "setString" and "stringForKey", check the docs.)